# Remove the spikes/triangles on a image

Tags: opencv, image-processing, emgucv, contour

I have an image that is with the spikes/small triangles on the outline border, like this:

[image: Orignal picture]

I would like to remove the un-wanted spikes/small triangles:

[image: Un-wanted spikes]

And output the image like this:

[image: Target image]

I have searched many posts on the web using OpenCV/Emgu CV but no luck.
The problem is the contour is not in equal spacing and I can not use any find peak functions to find them and remove them.

I have also used cubic spline to smooth the image, but it just destroyed the original image shape (too smooth) or just got a little effect on the spikes.

Could anyone who have ideas help me with this issue?

Comment: Have you tried a morphological closing?

Comment: Caution, you need to be very specific about what is a spike and what is not. An algorithm cannot guess what you have in mind and "but it is obvious" cannot be coded in a program. Can you provide an unambiguous definition of a spike ?

Comment: @Cris Luengo, I have been trying that, but it just got the thin lines removed and a more smooth shape.

Comment: @Yves Daoust, I can fully understand your comment and that is why it makes very difficult for me. In fact, I should call the un-wanted small triangles on the shape. In my real practice case, the small triangles are on the fixed positions of the object. But there is a big problem causes the difficulties to remove them for me. One is the object's orientation can be vary in a range of angle (e.g +/-15degree), and that makes the contours points have different distribution and starting point.

Comment: "on the fixed positions of the object": how can this be ? Do you mean that the object is always the same ??

Comment: What is a spike and what is not ?

Comment: What I want to remove is the positioning tabs on an object. Like this:
https://imgur.com/a/ADeltKY

Comment: The picture of object: https://imgur.com/a/YzEmxbu

Comment: You should have shown that in the first place ! Again an XY question.

Comment: Sorry for give an XY question and really thank you for helping.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Cris, a morphological closing is a good starting point.

In the picture below, I performed closing with an octognal kernel 49x49 (circular would be better), and took the difference with the original.

If you filter out the blobs by size (and possibly by shape), you will get the true spikes that you can subtract. The rest of the shape remains unchanged.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you Yves for this. I think this is good for me to try. From my previous comment, I apologize I am not that good at using morphological closing. If you can share your sample code with me it will be very helpful, but I think I can still try myself. Apprieate!

Comment: @HsiehJeremy: "I am not that good at using morphological closing", what do you mean, this is just two function calls ?

Comment: I have got it works as you shown above. ^^

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you want (its not accurate at all)

**OpenCV + Python**

```py
# Import preprocessors
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Read image
dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
im = cv2.imread(dir+'/im.png')

# Remove triangles
kernel = np.ones((5,5), np.uint8)
factor=11
im = cv2.dilate(im, kernel, iterations=factor)
im = cv2.erode(im, kernel, iterations=factor)

# Save the processed image
cv2.imwrite(dir+'/spike_res.png', im)
```

[image]

---

Update:

Maybe not related to **OpenCV** tag; but with **.NET** you can also use [**Erosion**](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/90a69d73-0e5a-3e27-cc52-5864f542b53e.htm) and [**Dialation**](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/88f713d4-a469-30d2-dc57-5ceb33210723.htm) of [**AForge**](http://aforgenet.com/).

Comment: Thanks Shamshirsaz. I am using .Net C# and I should check if there is numpy for C#.

Comment: You'r welcome :) I think you can also use AForge for C# @HsiehJeremy

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will also help.

Where:

- @contours is your list of contours after findContrours()
- @idx is the index of your contour
- @eps regulates how much the contour is approximated.

  ```
               cv::Mat approx;
               double eps = cv::arcLength(contours[idx], true) * 0.05;
               cv::approxPolyDP(contours[idx], approx, eps, true);
               approx.copyTo(contours[idx]);
  ```